How do I configure the v-calendar date-picker to allow selecting multiple dates
I'm using v-calendar (website, npm, GitHub).

The Calendar component allows me to respond to date clicks and highlight multiple dates, but it does not have pop-over functionality built in.
The DatePicker component has the pop-over functionality, and I can highlight multiple dates, but it also keeps track of and highlights the user selection with an internal field that I cannot seem to override. The last date clicked will always stay highlighted as a result, and even when I set value to null it will keep it highlighted. This means I cannot use the click to 'deselect' that date.
I found this answer but it seems to probably only apply to the Calendar (not picker) and the provided link is dead

What props am I missing to accomplish this?

Eventually I ended up using the following:

Use the DatePicker component so it has the pop-over functionality I need

Use the highlight key in the attributes prop to indicate what dates to mark as 'selected'

Adds/remove dates by responding to the dayclick event

On dayclick events, always reset the DatePicker's internal value using:
this.$refs.datePicker.updateValue(null, { clearIfEqual: true });

(This requires a ref to the DatePicker which is basic Vue functionality)


